# Merge branches with no "simultaneous" changes and keep branch structure

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

When I have a branch like this:

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

and merge topic back to master, I'll get this:

```
      A---B---C topic
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

Now, even if I remove the `topic` branch (let's say it was just a local development branch and I only push `master`) I'll still have the information, that there was a feature implemented starting at `E` and finished at `H`.

Is it possible to keep the same kind of imformation even, when there were no simultaneous commits on the `master` branch, while I was working on the `topic` branch? For example:

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E master
```

If I merge now, I'll get this:

```
D---E---A---B---C master/topic
```

If I remove the topic branch, I'll have no information in the future, where the feature implemented in the `topic` branch was finished. And even if I keep the branch, I don't know where it started.

I would prefer to keep both parents and have something like this:

```
      A---B---C topic
     /         \
D---E-----------F master
```

I think this is the default behavior of svn. Can I achieve the same with git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the `--no-ff` flag will create a merge commit even if the merge resolves to a fast-forward case.  Example (assuming you started at `C`):

```
git checkout E
git merge --no-ff C
```

More information is available at the [`git-merge(1)`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) documentation.

Comment: Oh, a RTFM question, sorry. Thanks though, exactly what I was looking for!